# National Holiday exclusion not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQuery-UI datepicker and Laravel-5.8

From the Controller, I sent NationalHoliday as JSON to the view

```
public function findNationalHoliday(Request $request)
{
   $nationalholidays               = HrNationalHoliday::select('holiday_date')->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))->get();
 return response()->json([
    'nationalholidays' => $nationalholidays,
 ]);        
}
```

javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var holidayDays = [];
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
      var air_id = $(this).val();

      var a = $(this).parent();

      var op = "";

      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{ route('
        get.leavecounts.all ') }}',
        data: {
          'id': air_id
        },
        dataType: 'json', //return data will be json
        success: function(data) {
          holidayDays = data.nationalholidays;
          console.log(data.nationalholidays);
        },
        error: function() {

        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

console.log(data.nationalholidays);

gives

```
0:
holiday_date: "2020-08-25 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
1:
holiday_date: "2020-08-26 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
2: {holiday_date: "2020-09-25 00:00:00"}
3: {holiday_date: "2020-11-30 00:00:00"}
4: {holiday_date: "2020-09-25 00:00:00"}
5: {holiday_date: "2020-09-30 00:00:00"}
6: {holiday_date: "2020-10-14 00:00:00"}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
```

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    holidayDays = holidayDays;

    function nationalDays(date) {
      var m = date.getMonth(),
        d = date.getDate(),
        y = date.getFullYear();
      for (i = 0; i < holidayDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, nationalDays) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
          console.log('bad:  ' + (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y + ' / ' + holidayDays[i]);
          return [false];
        }
      }
      return [true];
    };

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
      var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
      return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
    };

    $('.commencement_date').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',
      minDate: +1,
      setDate: new Date(),
      beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
      yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
    }).datepicker('setDate', '1');

  }); <
/script>
```

I want to disable both weekend and NationalHolidays.

But I observed that only weekends are disabled while national holidays are not.

How do I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Something seems off with your results. I would advise returning a simply Array of Date String: `[ "2020-08-25 00:00:00", "2020-08-26 00:00:00", "2020-09-25 00:00:00", ... ]`. It would also be best to send the dates back in a matching format: `"dd-mm-yy"`, so I would send back `[ "25-08-2020", "26-08-2020", "25-09-2020", ... ]` Otherwise return something that can be easily converted into a Date Object for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an example like:

```
  function nationalDays(date) {
    // Convert Date Object to String per Format
    var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date) + " 00:00:00";
    // Check for Date in Array
    var needle = holidayDays.indexOf(myDate);
    // Set Default
    var result = [true];
    // If Needle was found, make exception
    if (needle >= 0) {
      result = [false, "holiday", "National Holiday"];
    }
    // Return Results
    return result;
  };
```

See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

> **$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, options )**

> Format a date into a string value with a specified format.

The example above expects an Array of String. You seem to passing back an Array of Objects. If that is the case, you need to call the Object Key:

```
data.nationalholidays[0].holiday_date
```

This would need to adjust the function to something like:

```
  function nationalDays(date) {
    // Convert Date Object to String per Format
    var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date) + " 00:00:00";
    // Check for Date in Array
    var needle = -1;
    // Iterate Array of Objects
    $.each(holidayDays, function(i, d){
      if(d.holiday_date == myDate){
        needle = i;
      }
    });
    // Set Default
    var result = [true];
    // If Needle was found, make exception
    if (needle >= 0) {
      result = [false, "holiday", "National Holiday"];
    }
    // Return Results
    return result;
  };
```

More complete example:

```
$(function() {
  holidayDays = holidayDays;

  function nationalDays(date) {
    var myDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date) + " 00:00:00";
    var needle = holidayDays.indexOf(myDate);
    var result = [true];
    if (needle >= 0) {
      result = [false, "holiday", "National Holiday"];
    }
    return result;
  };

  function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
  };

  $('.commencement_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    duration: 'fast',
    minDate: +1,
    setDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
  }).datepicker('setDate', '1');

});
```